# How to select all textbox text and textbox opacity in WP application

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I use a `textbox` as an address bar for a WP browser application. I want to select all text when a user selects the `textbox` and also to modify the opacity.

I tried using `GotFocus` method to do that. I see that the whole text is selected for 1 second or so and then it is deselected. I also need to modify the opacity once the focus is on `textbox` and when the `textbox` loses focus. Using `GotFocus` method I can modify the opacity but when the focus is lost, when I set again the opacity percent nothing happens.

Can you give me a hint regarding the events that determine the text to be selected for a short period of time and for the opacity problem?

```
private void URLTextBox_GotFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{           
    URLTextBox.Opacity = 50;
    URLTextbOX.SelectAll();
}

private void URLTextBox_LostFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    URLTextBox.Opacity = 10;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try subscribing to one of the tunnelling events (`PreviewGotKeyboardFocus` and `PreviewLostKeyboardFocus`) instead of the `GotFocus` event.

Comment: Can you give me please a hint on how to implement this in my code ? I'm new to wpf and I can't find examples on tunneling event handling on internet....